# Modelling Zombie Outbreak

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelling, health

I know that there are many scripts (mostly in matlab) out there that address the spread of disease/zombie infection, but does anyone know of ways this has been developed/implemented in ArcGIS?

Essentially, how would you deal with taking into account issues of:

1. Terrain
2. Population density (by polygon or raster)

Would you write it in something like python or are there tools/models/scripts that already exist that I don't know about?

From what I can find, a majority of the modelling is done in math, [like here.](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/Zombies.pdf)

What steps would you take personally to answer the question: Given point X, how fast would a zombie outbreak spread given Y speed, Z terrain, or other variables?

The reason I ask, I teach GIS to a lot of young people and would love to use this as an opportunity to inspire them.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess what you should look for are agent based models (available through AgentAnalyst in ArcGis). I don't have an example yet, but i am sure that you could adapt one of those urban growth models out there to simulate a zombie infection

Comment: Here's how not to do it in ArcGIS: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/07/31998/

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.mapofthedead.com/ for some ideas?

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to check out the Agent Analyst extension. I hadn't heard of it until now. Should be interesting. Also, mapofthedead looks interesting, but I'm not sure how they model that.

Comment: @johns Can you explain why not, perhaps as an Answer?

Comment: At what scale were you thinking of doing the mapping and analysis, e.g. global, nationwide, state, county, city, zipcode, neighborhood, school? What "flavor" of zombie are you thinking of simulating, e.g. reanimated corpses vs. infected living subjects?

Comment: I'm not sure that zombie outbreaks are that deterministic. There are a lot of confounding factors in such an analysis - whether reanimation of already dead corpses is possible, the age of the intended audience (e.g. for kids, more likely around campsites; for adults, obligatory inclusion of stripclubs), whether animals are affected (zombie crows are particularly nasty), the lack of data on how well zombies can tunnel and cross streams, potential interactions between zombies and vampire populations, and of course the undecided issue of zombies vs godzilla. Good luck with it though.

Comment: @BradHards You're right. I am just thinking of starting with a simple model that accepts a few parameters and goes from there. I'm just not sure how to get started with implementing ODEs like that in ArcGIS. Also, for now, it would be something that takes advantage of basic public data, like a DEM, Census blocks, networks (streams/roads), etc.

Comment: @blah238 This would be on a county/regional level to start out. Simple for now. Showing "local" infestation as an appeal to youngsters.

Comment: @PolyGeo.  Perhaps I should rephrase my phrase to say:  Here’s an ESRI approach provided you accept the “bulletproof logic” linking zombie outbreaks to high crime and migraine medication use areas.