# Funny GIS research examples

Tags: research

for a Dutch studentsmagazine I'm writing an article about gis and how to use it in different Fields of Science Research. I'd like to put some fun stuff in there, like this study on Banksy (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/14498596.2016.1138246), but somehow this one seems to be the only one I can find. Weird, 'cause I guess there must be tons of funny, geeky research examples.

Comment: possibly throw in some zombies: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77131/modelling-zombie-outbreak

Comment: Can a car deliver a message to the ISS (international space station)? It's an add by Hundai that blends GIS, cars, satelite technology and -most important- love. Check it out here: https://youtu.be/3EOAXrTrsOE

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the actual GIS used in this example, but in 1992 there was a [shipping container of rubber ducks lost at sea](http://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/wilderness-resources/stories/what-can-28000-rubber-duckies-lost-at-sea-teach-us-about), and their travels taught us a lot about ocean currents and plastic pollution

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is a [species distribution model for bigfoot](http://www.qc.cuny.edu/Academics/Degrees/DMNS/Faculty%20Documents/Hickerson2.pdf).

It used the example of sasquatch sightings to highlight some of the flawed assumptions associated with species occurrence data. It also used it to start a discussion about the conceptual vs practical applications of SDMs.